# how can i export some data from my extension toward me?

Tags: php, email, google-chrome-extension

I wrote an extension to get user's email address and  current URL.
I need to export this data out of extension and get them.
I was searching for a way to do that but so far i was unable to do that.
I was thinking about sending email through extension containing above information to a mail-address like "example@mysite.com" but i guessed there must be different way to export this data to my own side...
However i will be so glad if someone show me a way to send data trough mail or any possible way.

please show me a way to do this

Answer (score 0):

A reasonable way to do it is to have an API exposed somewhere on the web - a web server with an interface to a database - and then just use XHR to POST it to a URL, that your web server will transform into a query to store it.

You should consider your users' privacy and always encrypt this sensitive data in transit with HTTPS.

You could potentially use Google App Engine for that purpose, or any web hosting that provides database access. Be mindful of potential abuse and always validate inputs.

*This answer is of course very broad - but so is your question. I won't try to provide a detailed example.*